# How to take a branch applied to branch A and apply it to branch B

Tags: git

I did some work to fix a production issue, in a branch called myfix. The problem is, I cant remember what branch I based myfix on, i.e. I dont know what I checked out before I started mofifying the code. I assume it was feature/xx, which is what we were all working on at the time.

How they want to put my fix in production, which is master.

Basically all the changes I did in myfix, on an unknown branch, need to be applied to master.

The problem is that myfix will be on top of a branch which contains other stuff, so I cant just merge myfix with master.

I am guessing one option is to checkout master, then checkout specific files from myfix.  Is this the best approach?

Only 3 files were changed. If worst comes to worse, I could probably hand edit the files to add the fix, although errors might get introduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick --no-commit myfix
```

You'll bring in the working tree all of `myfix`'s last commit's changes, but witout committing yet.

At this point you'll be able to edit whatever you want *then* commit it when you're happy with it.

---

Alternatively, if you already know the only files you need brought from this hotfix, and don't want to take the other changes made in the same commit, you can

```
git checkout master
git checkout myfix -- path/to/file1 path/to/file2 path/to/file3
git add path/to/file1 path/to/file2 path/to/file3
git commit -m "Useful message"
```

It'll make a new commit on master where these 3 files are exactly like on `myfix` branch (which, depending on your needs, might not be what you want).

Comment: Thanks for your help. When you say "bring in the working tree of all of myfixes changes" does this mean that it will pickup the 3 files I edited and committed in myfix (what I want), or everything which is in the branch which myfix was taken from as well?  e.g. if I based myfix on feature/xx will I get all of the commits to feature/xx which are not on master yet?

Comment: Also, do you know if there is a way to find out what branch I based myfix on?  it could have been develop, master, feature/xx or anything - I cant remember unfortunately and didnt think to write it down.  I assumed git would know.

Comment: @JohnLittle To answer in reverse order : no solid way to know which branch your branch was based on. Branches come and go in a repo tree but they don't define anything permanently. To your first question : cherry-pick will only replay changes brought by the last commit on `myfix`, **not** take it as a merge source, or even worse overwrite master with `myfix` files. That's the reason it can also generate conflicts : git tries to replay on top of master state whatever was changed in given commit (here, last one in `myfix`)

Comment: Try it out, you'll see the result. *(to cancel an in-progress cherry-pick : `git cherry-pick --abort`)*

Comment: Awesome, ill try it. The next problem is how to find the commit sha which cherry pick needs. I see there is git rev-parse command, but I am not sure if the result is correct (e.g. if its showring the commit I did locally, or the commit of the merge I did, or the commiit on the origin after the merge, or even if all 3 are the same (no idea)

Comment: `git cherry-pick myfix` will pick the branch's *last* commit, no need for its SHA-1. If you committed anything *after* your hotfix on this branch, yes, you'll have to find it with `git log -10 --oneline myfix` for example

Comment: Awesome. So this is my flow: git checkout master; git cherry-pic --no-commit myfix; git checkout -b my-master-hotfix; git add *; git commit -m "my master hotfix"; git push -u origin my-master-hotrix

Comment: @JohnLittle Sounds great to me :-) (just mind the "k" in cherry-pick but it's obviously a typo) You'll be able to then create a pull request `my-master-hotfix > master` and it should be fine